# JQuery - adding value to input, but one input has no ".value" property

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I want to have a function, that writes to an input like a real human (by triggering all the events)
This is the code I wrote:

Take a close look to the part "element.value += text_array[i]".

```
function FillInText(element_id, text){
    var element = $("#"+element_id);
    element.focus();
    element.click();

    var kdown = jQuery.Event("keydown");
    var kup = jQuery.Event("keyup");

    var text_array = text.split("");

    for(i = 0; i < text_array.length; i++){
        var code = text_array[i].charCodeAt(0);
        kdown.which = code;
        kup.which = code;

        element.trigger(kdown);
        element.change();
        element.value += text_array[i];
        element.trigger(kup);        
    }
    element.blur();
}
```

This code is perfect for any input and it works 99% of the time. But there is one input field, whose value isn't stored in its ".value" property. When I try to set/get the value using that, nothing returns.
However, I CAN get it using JQuery's "val()" function.

But whats perfect about "Element.value" is that you can ADD some value to the existing one. As far as I know, you can't do that with "val()". 
Althought you could use:

```
val(function(index,currentvalue){
        return currentvalue + text_array[i];
});
```

The code undestands it like: 
previousValue is "a" and addedValue is "b". 
The input field was "a", it takes the "b" and adds it together, then puts in into the input. so it doesn't ADD "a", but rather deletes the existing and then adds "ab" to it. When using "element.value += 'b'", it doesn't even touch the previousValue, instead it just adds it to it. 
I would want a function that's like:

```
element.val() += "b";
```

I hope you can understand my problem... I'm sorry if I have explained it badly.

Comment: What kind of `<input>` is that one?

Comment: I think the click event should come before focus.

Comment: @Jack Bashford I think it's a normal text-input, but if you want to research by yourself(which I would really appreciate c:), the source is "https://signup.live.com/", it is the "Verification" input.

Comment: @Barmar it doesn't matter, it works on every other input field.

Comment: There's no need for `text_array`. You can iterate through `text` itself, and use `text.charCodeAt(i)`.

Comment: Please update the question to show and example of "But there is one input field, whose value isn't stored in its ".value" property." here

Comment: Your website is signup.live.com? Or you're trying to write an extension that runs in other sites?

Comment: I can't see the verification input when I go to that page. I guess I'd have to go through the signup process to get to the part you're talking about, but I don't want to do that (when I enter my email, it says it's already in use). Anyway, I suspect they have custom input handling for that field, which is why your code doesn't work.

Comment: @Barmar No, sadly I'm not Bill Gates :) I want to write an extension that runs on signup.live.com

Comment: You need to find the code on that page that processes the input, and see what events it's using so you can emulate them.

Comment: @Barmar when I look through all the events it triggeres, it just the same as every other input, where it works.

Comment: You have to look at what events their code is listening for. You must not be triggering the right ones.

Comment: @Barmar I'm sorry, I was looking for the wrong input. Here are the events the input is listening to:
blur()
change()
click()
copy()
cut()
dblclick() - double click
focus()
focusin()
focusout()
keydown()
keyup()
paste()

Comment: In general you should not add SOLVED to a title, accepting an answer is enough here - IF you solve it yourself, it is also OK to post your OWN answer and accept that one.

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss I did answer my question, but I can't accept it. There was an Error like "You need 2 more days to accept your own questions". It was my first ever question on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your code should work for any inputs.

`.value` is a DOM property, but `element` contains a jQuery object, not a DOM element. You can get the corresponding DOM element by indexing it:

```
element[0].value += test_array[i];
```

You can add to the value with jQuery `.val()` by using a function:

```
element.val(function(_, old_value) {
    return old_value + test_array[i];
}
```

Comment: It does work on all other of the input-fields and as far as I know, you can target all DOM properties when you have a JQuery element. Also, I think you missunderstood my question(it's most likely my bad explanation) The code you wrote is EXACTLY the same as I did, and that doesn't work. If you could please read the question carefully, I would really appreciate it, because I see you have a great experience.

Comment: My code is not exactly the same as yours. I wrote `element[0].value`, you don't have `[0]`. I have never heard of being able to use DOM properties on jQuery objects. I just tried it myself and it didn't work.

Comment: use this: https://jsfiddle.net/ruxvop5L/ it is almost the same code, only in my language but it should work. It's completely spaghetti code, I know that. It is in development, so its (as I think) a bit easier to understand for me. I'm not that experienced. But Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The fiddle has no HTML and never calls the function. How am I supposed to use it?

Comment: When I added HTML and the jQuery library, your fiddle works: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/gj91ocfL/1/

Answer (score 0):

In general jQuert's selector like `$("#element")` is an array contains element(s), e.g. `[DOMElement, DOMElement,...]` and to use pure Java Script properties or methods use `$("#element")[0]`

https://www.w3schools.com/jquERY/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

But in pure JS `document.getElementById("element")` is pure element object.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp

Check this

```js
//jQuery's prototype
jQuery.fn.FillInText = function(text) {
var el = $(this),kc,kd,ku
  el.focus().click();
  for(var i=0;i < text.length;i++) {
     kc = text.charCodeAt(i);
     kd = jQuery.Event("keydown", { keyCode: kc });
     ku = jQuery.Event("keyup", { keyCode: kc });
    el.trigger(kd);
    el.change();
    el[0].value += text[i]; // + "b"
    el.trigger(ku);
  }
}

//Test listening to keyup, keydown events
$("#inp").on("keydown keyup", function(e) {
  console.log(e.type + ": " + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode))
})

//Go..
$("#inp").FillInText("This is test string")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="inp" />
```